# Is there any way to synthesis image in Android native API or using HTML5

Tags: android, html

I want to build a mobile app with the following function:

Let user choose an image, then we generate a picture base on that picture.

- The generated picture has some specified text with specified font.
- There is another picture, which may be a PNG file, used as foreground.
- Output that generated picture to user's device.

Is there any way to synthesis image in Android API or using HTML5?

---

I prefered use some Javascript way to do this, so I can easily build the app cross platform, but I don't know whether JS can do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this purpose you can use HTML5 canvas https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Drawing_Graphics_with_Canvas

If you want to code this using Android API you can use Canvas:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html

By the way there is a good guide "Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently" http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html